# How to make bootstrap html input longer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i want make my input field longer as the same 2 fields above him, look the picture please:
[image]

My HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-3">
        <label for="TripNumber">Trip Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TripNumber" placeholder="Trip Number">
    </div>
</div>
```

I failed to do it with the boostrap grid system alone.
I cant change to col-lg-3 is not work, look at the comments.

Comment: Simply change `col-lg-3` to `col-lg-6`

Comment: didnt make it longer, just adding to the end of the input more 3 boostrap section white spaces

Comment: If so, something is wrong with you whole form

Comment: my form is just: <form style="margin-top:20px"></form>

Comment: Post all of the code, or create a fiddle/bootply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code............

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
            <label for="TripNumber">Trip Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TripNumber"     placeholder="Trip Number">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: didnt make loner the input, just make more "3" after the input with white spaces https://ibb.co/e6Z98v

Comment: Can you give me the live URL/Link?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/nW9hyWEjco
in the URL its work perfect, on my machine not work properly, why is?

Comment: Its maybe **HTML5** markup issue......If i could not see the code i can not give appropriate answer....

Comment: but why on my machine the code didnt work properly ? need to add some packages to my view ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137433/discussion-between-md-abdul-momin-and-ballon-ura).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved adding one of the `col-` classes in the input itself.

In your case, replace `col-lg-3` for `col-lg-6` in the `div` and **add** `col-lg-6` in the `input` as well:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
    <label for="TripNumber">Trip Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6" id="TripNumber" placeholder="Trip Number">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label for="TripNumber">Trip Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TripNumber" placeholder="Trip Number">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace

> col-lg-3

with

> col-lg-6

in `class` attr